# Android - how to open voicemail settings to set number using Intent in LOLLIPOP

Tags: java, android

I'm trying open to voicemail settings in android lollipop devices but it is not working.

**This is my code**

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(TelephonyManager.ACTION_CONFIGURE_VOICEMAIL);
            startActivity(intent);
```

When i run this code i get problem in

```
startActivity(intent);
```

**My AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

Where is the problem?

Need help thanks.

Comment: **all permissions have been granted successfully**

Comment: **i need to open the voicemail settings activity to make changes to voicemail configuration**